# Queueing Theory - Probability that all jobs have been served?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Suppose I have M/M/1 system with $\lambda = 4$ per hour and $\mu = 5$ per hour. How can I find out if all jobs have been served after, say, 8 hours? At first I thought about doing $P(n > 40)$ since $\mu = 5$ means 5 arrive, on average, per hour but I'm pretty sure that's not the right way to do it. I don't know how it actually goes, however.

Comment: $\mu=5$ means 5 are served every hour, not arrived

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the probability that the queue is empty?

Comment: It starts empty. If you mean at the end, then that's what I want to know, but after some time has passed (in my initial post, that time is 8 hours).

Comment: Oooooh. I get it.